# Extract images in .jpg format from binary using unpickle (python)

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to extract images from `CIFAR-10` data binary file, i.e. `data_batch_1.bin` as `.jpg`.

But while doing unpickle I am getting an error.

My code is:

```python
from PIL import Image
import numpy 

def unpickle(file):
    import pickle
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo)
    return dict


def save_as_image(img_flat):
    """
        Saves a data blob as an image file.
    """

    # consecutive 1024 entries store color channels of 32x32 image 
    img_R = img_flat[0:1024].reshape((32, 32))
    img_G = img_flat[1024:2048].reshape((32, 32))
    img_B = img_flat[2048:3072].reshape((32, 32))
    img = numpy.dstack((img_R, img_G, img_B))
    im = Image.fromarray(img)
    im.show()

abc = unpickle("/home/ubuntu/visit/cifar-10-batches-bin/data_batch_1.bin")
#print(abc)
data = abc["data"]
save_as_image(data[0])
```

I am getting an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load.py", line 24, in <module>
    abc = unpickle("/home/ubuntu/visit/cifar-10-batches-bin/data_batch_1.bin")
  File "load.py", line 7, in unpickle
    dict = pickle.load(fo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\x06'
```

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Are these the files from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html ?

Comment: @bouteillebleu yes these files are from the above site.